# Laravel Scout with Elastic search not working

Tags: elasticsearch, laravel-5, laravel-scout

I tried

- Using Elastic search with Laravel scout with packages

  ```
  "laravel/scout": "^1.0",
  "tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic": "^1.0"
  ```
- Ran Elasticsearch server in localhost:9200 and created index and gave necessary config's,
- added searchable trait's to the model,
- and imported data to index like

  ```
  php artisan scout:import "App\story"
  Imported [App\story] models up to ID: 4
  All [App\story] records have been imported.
  ```

But when I do a search it returns an empty array

```
 story::search("the")->get()
 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#754
      all: [],
 }
```

when I do curl also it shows like,

```
// http://localhost:9200/author/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*

      {
        "took": 1,
        "timed_out": false,
        "_shards": {
          "total": 5,
          "successful": 5,
          "failed": 0
        },
        "hits": {
          "total": 0,
          "max_score": null,
          "hits": [
            
          ]
        }
      }
```

When I adding the record without index in ES the model throws an error like `index not found`. But after adding data and all, it seems empty. Did I miss anything?

The whole same works fine with algolia.

Comment: It looks like your index is empty, if curl returns no records.

Comment: My issue is data is not adding to my index via scout interface in laravel.

Comment: I had this exact same problem, not sure if you ever figured it out, but I didn't.  I ended up not using Scout

Answer (score 4):

Set  QUEUE=sync or you could turn off queue on config/scout.php.

Had the same issue: https://github.com/ErickTamayo/laravel-scout-elastic/issues/43

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. 
Delete your index in Elasticsearch and run:

```
php artisan scout:import App\\story
```

Let scout create it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using elastic search, check the error log - I had:

```
sudo su 

tail -f /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log


high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [minbqqKpRV-umA0DPxkuww][mihai-MS-7A72][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 28.9gb[6.3%], shards will be relocated away from this node; currently relocating away shards totalling [0] bytes; the node is expected to continue to exceed the high disk watermark when these relocations are complete
```

IF that`s the case,disable the disk check,at least for testing

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings \
     -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": false}'
```

Or make those changes permanent in elasticsearch.yml and restart the service.